# Finding the max after Counting with Specific Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the department with the maximum amount of null assigned.
Here is the table Class:

```
Dept    Assigned
CSCE    
CSCE    
ELEG     4
ELEG     
MATH     
ELEG
```

So since CSCE and ELEG have the largest amount of null assigned, I want to output.

```
Dept   Max(Count)
CSCE   2
ELEG   2
```

Here is what I have:

```
Select Dept, Max(Countt)
from (Select Dept, Count(Dept) as Countt
      from Class
      where assigned is null group by Dept
     );
```

However, it is outputting the count for all the Dept including Math. How can I fix that?

I am using Oracle.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select d.Dept, cnt
from (select c.Dept, Count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from Class c 
      where c.assigned is null
      group by c.Dept
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way:

```
select count(*), dept from table
where assigned is null
group by dept
having count(*) = (select max(c) from (select count(*) as c from table
                   where assigned is null
                   group by dept) as t)
```